# Find expectation of of $max(X,5)$ from given probability mass function

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Let $X$ be random variable with pmf

> $P(X=n)=\dfrac{1}{10},n=1,2...10$
>
> $0$ otherwise

Find $E(max(X,5))$

Let $Y=max(X,5)$

$P(Y=y) =
\begin{cases}
5,  & \text{if $X \le5$ } \\[2ex]
X, & \text{if $X >5$ }
\end{cases}$

$E(y)=\sum yP(Y=y)$

$E(y)=E(5)+E(X)$

$=5+\dfrac{6}{10}+\dfrac{7}{10}+\dfrac{8}{10}+\dfrac{9}{10}+\dfrac{10}{10}$

I am not sure if I am going in right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this it is not necessary (and not handsome) to go for the distribution of derived random variable $\max(X,5)$.

You can just work out:$$\mathbb E\max(X,5)=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\max(n,5)P(X=n)=\frac1{10}\sum_{n=1}^{10}\max(n,5)$$

Comment: WOW Thanks! I got the answer instantly. But please help me out in my method as well. Where did I do wrong .

Comment: You stated that $\mathbb EY=\mathbb E5+\mathbb EX=5+\mathbb EX$. That would have been correct for $Z:=\mathbb E[5+X]$ (linearity of expectation), but not for $Y:=\max(5,X)$. Correct would be a working out of $$\mathbb EY=\mathbb E[Y\mid X\leq 5]P(X\leq 5)+\mathbb E[Y\mid X>5]P(X>5)=5\cdot\frac12+\mathbb E[Y\mid X>5]\frac12=5\cdot\frac12+[\frac15\cdot6+\cdots+\frac15\cdot10]\frac12$$So actually your answer misses the factor $\frac12$ following $5$.